# DataTable fix width with vertical scroll bar

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, datatables

I am using DataTable.

I have following tables:

**Table 1**

[image: Data Table 1]

**Table 2**
[image: Data Table 2]
This is my initialization code:

```
$('#invoice-content-table').dataTable({
    "bPaginate": false,
    "sScrollY": "150px",
    "bPaginate": false,
    "bLengthChange": false,
    "bFilter": false,
    "bSort": false,
    "bInfo": false,
    "bAutoWidth": false,
    "bDestroy": true,
    "aoColumns": [{
            "sWidth": "170px"
        }, {
            "sWidth": "30px"
        }, {
            "sWidth": "30px"
        }, {
            "sWidth": "40px"
        }, {
            "sWidth": "25px"
        }, {
            "sWidth": "25px"
        }, {
            "sWidth": "25px"
        }, {
            "sWidth": "25px"
        }, {
            "sWidth": "25px"
        }, {
            "sWidth": "30px"
        }, {
            "sWidth": "50px"
        }

    ]
});
```

Is there a way to fix `scroll-y` to scroll even if it does not contains any data ?

Comment: The width doesn't seem to be changing on their sample - at least not in my chrome on my mac - http://datatables.net/examples/basic_init/scroll_y.html

Comment: actually it is. their sample contains 57 rows, i tried it with 3 rows, it resizes..

Comment: Tricky - sorry - hadn't gotten into it, just seems to go over the top.  Any way CSS can bail you out here?